# Matlab sequentialfs local minima

Tags: matlab, minimum, feature-selection

I am wondering if there's a way to keep sequentialfs going after it finds a local minimum so you can make sure the model it selects is always the global minimum. I looked into the options and a little into the function's code, as far as I can tell it stops as soon as it finds a local minimum, which might not be optimal in a feature selection task.

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong, and if there is indeed a way to avoid local minima.

Comment: You may have to jump out of the current searching region after finding a local minimum. The region is where you start with. Just jump by a certain amount. But the detailed parameters depend on your exact function.

Comment: how would you jump? sequentialfs is finding features that fit the model by minimizing some value based on a randomly selected training/testing set combination, right? So I'm trying to maximize the R-squared of the final model, it finds one, how to I tell it to jump to a different location in that space?